# Using package iflang with IfLanguageName doesn't work

Tags: babel, languages, documentclass-writing

I create a document class `testclass`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrartcl}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[DIV=10,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
...
```

And I want to use it in my tex file.

```
\documentclass{testclass}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{iflang}

\IfLanguageName{ngerman}{\title{German Title}}
\IfLanguageName{english}{\title{English Title}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}

\IfLanguageName{ngerman}{Test1}
\IfLanguageName{english}{Test2}
```

Then is all fine. But If I set `selectlanguage` to `ngerman` I get both contents. What did I maybe missunderstanding?

Comment: Please make sure your examples are complete. None of this `...` and make sure your `.tex` example is complete

Comment: `\IfLanguageName` takes 3 arguments, you are only giving it two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\IfLanguageName` takes three argumnents in the form of

- a language name
- true branch
- false branch

In all 4 uses of `\IfLanguage` you are missing the `false` branch, add them and it works ok.

Comment: Thank you. RTFM for myself ;-)